# How do I get Alexa Lambda FN not to throw Type Error when using alexa-sdk node lib?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

**Problem Shaping**

I've created an Alexa app using `'alexa-sdk'` node library to build a AWS lambda Alexa application.

```
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const handlers = { /* ... */ };

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.execute();
};
```

This code *used* to work just fine, until I uploaded again, then it stopped working!  When I uploaded the same version of code, I suddenly started getting Type errors.  No code was changed.  Here is how I'm zipping up the node lambda application, for later AWS upload.

```
"dependencies": {
  "alexa-sdk": "^1.0.9"
},
"scripts": {
  "zip": "zip -r function.zip package.json *.js node_modules && mkdir -p ../dist && mv function.zip ../dist"
}
```

You can verify correct zipping by running `zipinfo ../dist/${lambdaName}` ( replacing `lambdaName` with my lambda's function name).

The error comes from when I test this on Alexa Lambda, with a default test file.

**Error dump:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
at AlexaRequestEmitter.ValidateRequest (/var/task/node_modules/alexa-sdk/lib/alexa.js:135:36)
at AlexaRequestEmitter.HandleLambdaEvent (/var/task/node_modules/alexa-sdk/lib/alexa.js:117:25)
at AlexaRequestEmitter.value (/var/task/node_modules/alexa-sdk/lib/alexa.js:92:31)
at exports.handler (/var/task/AgrihackGardenFn.js:78:9)
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you set defaults, or update your lambda test data to be one of Alexa's request shape.

```
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const handlers = { /* ... */ };

const returnDefaultEvent = (event) => Object.assign(
  {},
  {
    request: {
      locale: 'en-US',
      type: 'LaunchRequest'
    },
    session: {
      application: {
        applicationId: 'applicationId'
      },
      user: {
        userId: 'userId'
      }
    }
  },
  event
);

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  const alexa = Alexa.handler(returnDefaultEvent(event), context);
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.execute();
};
```

I wrote this because fixing this in code was easier than updating AWS test contract way.  Turns out, this library requests even more of the object shape than `request` to have a value (see default FN).

This allows the Alexa application to resume running, and you can test through the Alexa developer portal web UI, if you like!

No idea why the code suddenly broke on AWS lambda, but this monkey patch resolves the situation.